# What is the Ruby equivalent of Java's TreeSet<Integer> (self balancing binary tree)?

Tags: ruby, binary-tree, avl-tree

I want to use a self balancing binary tree to play around with some algorithms, but I'm having difficulty finding the Ruby equivalent of Java's TreeSet (or C#'s SortedSet).

I have found web code like:

https://github.com/nahi/avl_tree#readme

https://github.com/MishaConway/binary_search_tree

http://blog.mikedll.com/2009/09/balanced-avl-binary-search-tree.html

I'd rather rely on something that is in Ruby's Standard Library. Isn't there some class in Ruby's Standard Library for this? I can't seem to find much besides [RubyTree](http://rubytree.rubyforge.org/), which I don't believe is self-balancing.

(I'll keep Googling til I find it, or someone on this forum points me in the right direction :) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use SortedSet from set as shown below

```
require 'set'
 s = SortedSet.new([8,2,9,3])
 => #<SortedSet: {2, 3, 8, 9}>
```

pass argument array as paramter

Comment: So, if I wanted to determine the average amount of time it takes to look up a key in a randomly-generated balanced binary search tree, I could use SortedSet? I'm trying to see where it says SortedSet is implemented as a balanced binary search tree... hmmm

Comment: @FoolishChap It is a red-black tree. See https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/set.rb#L540

Comment: In MRI, it is implemented using `Hash`, in all other Ruby implementations, it is implemented using some sort of self-balancing search tree. The Ruby Language Specification doesn't specify any particular data structure or algorithm; in fact, the Ruby Language Specification completely ignores the *entire* standard library. So, you cannot rely on that.